# where to find httpd.conf file on shared hosting?

Tags: shared-hosting

I am using A2 hosting shared server and need httpd.conf file for wildcard subdomain but I am not able to find httpd.conf on a shared server. where I can find this?

Comment: Apache config files cannot be modified at most shared hosting providers, your only option would be to use .htaccess files.

Comment: @MaarenDev I upload my project on app.example.net. user gets registered on this domain and get his unique subdomain e.g john.example.net like saas apps.I want to redirect subdomain users on app.example.net but url must stay same. e.g john.example.net. how to achieve this using .htaccess

Comment: So you want every subdomain to go to the same ip?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes because there are app.example.net routes group and {subdomain}.example.net routes group in my app.example.net project.